# Plotly not Displaying Figure in Browser when Run in Visual Studio Code (VS Code)

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, plotly

I am encountering an issue where Plotly plots, generated with a simple code snippet like the one below, do not display in the browser when executed within Visual Studio Code. The same code works perfectly fine when run in the terminal, opening a browser window and displaying the figure.

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
fig = go.Figure()
fig.show()
```

However, when executed within VS Code, it seems like the code is running without any errors, but no browser window opens, and the figure is not displayed. It appears as though VS Code is waiting for a window to open or assuming a window is already open, but there is no visible output.

Has anyone else encountered a similar problem or does anyone have suggestions on how to troubleshoot and resolve this issue? Any insights or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please [edit] to also describe how exactly are you running it within VS Code. Using VS Code's launch.json + debugger? Using an extension like CodeRunner? Entering commands from the terminal?

Comment: I copied your code into VSCODE, saved it as a file, and ran it in the terminal and it produced the graph correctly. How did you run it?

Comment: I copied your code and it ran on my machine without any problems. Check your browser settings, firewall settings, etc. Also how do you execute the code? Do you want to use `Run Python File`? Why do you think the code runs without errors? Please describe your actions and results in detail.